# how can I register a post_meta field in an existing CPT and then call it again with get_post_custom()?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, register-taxonomy

I would like to add a post_meta (test_meta_1234) field to an existing CPT (organizer) of an external plugin.

With register_meta() it doesn't work. 
But a taxonomy I can add to the same CPT with register_taxonomy().

Code Sample:

```
register_meta('post', 'test_meta_1234', array(
    'object_subtype' => 'organizer',
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'single' => true,
    'type' => 'string',
    'description' => 'Test Meta 1234',
  )
);

register_taxonomy(
'genre',
'organizer',
 array(
    'label' => __( 'Genre' ),
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'genre' ),
    'hierarchical' => true,
 )
);

$otherPostTypesFull = new stdClass();
$otherPostTypes     = get_post_types();
foreach($otherPostTypes as $postType => $postTypeSlug){
 $args = array(
              'post_type'         => $postTypeSlug,
              'numberposts'             => -1
            );
 foreach(get_posts( $args ) as $faPosts){
  $otherPostTypesFull->$postTypeSlug->post_meta   = get_post_custom($faPosts->ID);
  $otherPostTypesFull->$postTypeSlug->taxonomies  = get_object_taxonomies( $postTypeSlug, 'objects' );
 }
}
var_dump($otherPostTypesFull);
```

The taxonomy is added to the CPT, but not the post_meta (test_meta_1234).

Why can't I see the post_meta field with get_post_custom()?

---

update 1:

The CPT did not support 'custom-fields', so now first check and add this:

```
`if(!post_type_supports( 'organizer', 'custom-fields' )){
 add_post_type_support( 'organizer', 'custom-fields' );
}`
```

The custom-field 'test_meta_1234' is still not registered yet.
Why that?

Comment: If `get_post_custom()` does not include the meta `test_meta_1234`, then it's likely that your post doesn't have that meta. And does the post type actually support *custom fields* (`custom-fields`)? It's required by `register_meta()`.

Comment: Many thanks to Sally for the valuable input. 
The CPT 'organizer' support custom fields do not.
I have added

`if(!post_type_supports( 'ecwd_organizer', 'custom-fields' )){
  add_post_type_support( 'ecwd_organizer', 'custom-fields' );
}`

and now supports the CPT 'organizer', 'custom-fields'.

But the custom field 'test_meta_1234' is still not registered.
Why that?

Comment: Actually, what do you mean by "registered"? Are you sure the post has the specified custom field? How did you add the custom field to the post? And how do you register the CPT - what's your code or the plugin if you're using a plugin?

Comment: I thought that with register_meta() a custom-field (post-meta) can be registered identical to register_taxonomy() a caregory/keyword. 
Is this the case?

Comment: Ok, so my initial assumption was that you wanted to be able to retrieve the meta value when retrieving the post via the REST API. So that explains my first comment, particularly the last two sentences (except, I meant "required by the REST API"). Secondly, I'm not sure of other uses of the meta added/registered via `register_meta()`, but the one that's common is so that the registered meta is accessible via the REST API - i.e. `http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/<post type>` would include the meta in the `meta` property of the API response.

Comment: But still, a post need to actually have the specified meta - i.e. the post has that meta and it's value was set as well. And you can set it programmatically using `update_post_meta()` or `add_post_meta()`. Or use the standard Custom Fields editor/metabox (see [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/)), or a plugin like Advanced Custom Fields (ACF).

Comment: Thank you so much, Sally. I have now understood that custom fields cannot be registered and is register_meta for the REST API.
Many thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

custom fields (post_meta) cannot be registered.

register_meta only works in conjunction with the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

It'll probably be way easier to just use https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

If not check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740907/how-to-add-custom-field-to-custom-post-type) which points you to [this page](http://wptheming.com/2010/08/custom-metabox-for-post-type/)

Comment: Many thanks for the input. The Custom Post Type already exists from another plugin. The post_meta field should be stored in the system so that I can reuse it in a table as a column. So I don't need a MetaBox or any other plugin, because they manage the data for the field post_meta internally in the plugin. I want to store the additional field with hardCode.